# Change html div property based on URL variable being set

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="block" style="width:40.5%; margin-top: 1%;   
margin-left:-6.5%; height: 15%; position: fixed">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to change the value of the the margin-left (or any margin) based on whether the URL has "id" set. For example generally the home page will be "index.php" however based on a search the URL can then be something like "index.php?id=1". If the "id" parameter does not exist in the URL I would like the margin-left to be say -6.5% and if the "id" parameter does exist I would like the margin-left to be say 6.5%. Apologies I know I'm probably missing an easy solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can't post a little HTML with CSS and expect people to do the rest for you. This isn't free programming request site.

Comment: I'm not sure what to try and I can post more of my code if you like

Comment: Where is this URL variable? How are you getting the variable. By variable I assume you mean url parameter of **id**. The source code you have showing doesn't show how you are getting the url parameter. If you have more **relevant** source code then yes display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'll need to use some JavaScript to check over the url to see if 'id' exists. If it exists then we just tell it to update the 'margin-left' property for that div.

```
function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
  function (m, key, value) {
    vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
}
var getId = getUrlVars()["id"];
if (getId) { 
  var mainBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("block")[0];
  mainBlock.style.marginLeft = "6.5%";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/30pt30cm/1/

Comment: Absolutely what I needed!! Excellent! Glad you understood unlike some other members